# Regression loss function is nan

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, regression

I'm a beginner with ANN and DL in general. I have a regression task with a target of 2-dimensions, my dataset only have 46 samples (small dataset I think).
I tried the code below that does a regression with only one output which works normally.

When I change to a two dimensional regression, my loss function becomes equal to NaN.
I tried to change the optimizer and fix the dropout rate, but nothing changed, any solution?

```
import numpy
import pandas
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

#load data
dataframe = pandas.read_excel("data1.xlsx")
dataframe.isnull().any()

dataset = dataframe.values

X = dataset[:, 0:5]
Y = dataset[:,5:7]

def baseline_model():
    #create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=5, kernel_initializer='normal', activation 
='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(2, kernel_initializer='normal'))

    #compile model
    #model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model



#fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)

estimators=[]
estimators.append(('standardize', StandardScaler()))
estimators.append(('mlp', KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=50, batch_size=32, verbose=0)))
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)

kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state = seed)
results = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, Y, cv=kfold)

print ("Result: %.2f (%.2f) MSE" %(results.mean(), results.std()))
```

Comment: NaN are sometimes due to too large learning rate. Try to set it 10 times lower, or so.

Comment: I think your dataset is way too small. I guess your model have a big bias error and you are additionally using regurlarization, dropping 50% of neurons after the first hidden layer. Can you share your dataset?

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issues and searched solution in many places. But apparently, it's because I put wrong label in my dataset. It should be 0,1,2,... n but I made 1,2,3,....n. It should be started from zero. After I changed the label, it works well now.